# Connect two GWT applications - Client/Server

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, gwt-rpc, mgwt

What is the best way to connect two GWT applications, a web (Client) and a mobile Application (Server with GWT Mobile).

I tried to do that with RPC but it has not worked.

The database is in the server part.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way if you ask me is to use REST instead of gwt rpc.
Please take a look at [RestyGWT](https://resty-gwt.github.io/) for your GWT-client application, on server - any JAX-RS implementation will do, We're using [Glassfish Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) on a tomcat - works like charm.